# How can I reset a react component including all transitively reachable state?

Tags: reactjs

I occasionally have react components that are conceptually stateful which I want to reset.  The ideal behavior would be equivalent to removing the old component and readding a new, pristine component.

React provides a method `setState` which allows setting the components own explicit state, but that excludes implicit state such as browser focus and form state, and it also excludes the state of its children.  Catching all that indirect state can be a tricky task, and I'd prefer to solve it rigorously and completely rather that playing whack-a-mole with every new bit of surprising state.

Is there an API or pattern to do this?

**Edit:**  I made a trivial example demonstrating the `this.replaceState(this.getInitialState())` approach and contrasting it with the `this.setState(this.getInitialState())` approach: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emn13/kdrzk6gh/) - `replaceState` is more robust.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

To ensure that the implicit browser state you mention and state of children is reset, you can add a [`key` attribute](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#option-2-resetting-state-with-a-key) to the root-level component returned by `render`; when it changes, that component will be thrown away and created from scratch.

```
render: function() {
    // ...
    return <div key={uniqueId}>
        {children}
    </div>;
}
```

There's no shortcut to reset the individual component's local state.

Comment: Just out of curiosity when you say 'component will be thrown away and created from scratch' do you mean the virtual DOM will be thrown away and created from scratch but the DOM updates will still happen based on the diff algorithm?

Comment: @nimgrg No, the real DOM elements will be recreated as well. (The virtual DOM is already recreated on every render so if you want to keep the real DOM, simply don't set a `key` in this case.)

Comment: @EamonNerbonne On React 0.8, keys are only used to distinguish between sibling elements in an array and were ignored at the root. See https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/590.

Comment: Note `replaceState()` and `getInitialState()` are both deprecated in the new ES6 class-style reactjs.  Use `this.setState(this._getInitialState())` instead.  Also you can't name your own state initializer function `getInitialState()` - react throws a warning - call it anything else and explicitly do `state = this._getInitialState()` in the top level of the class.

Comment: I tried using Date.now() for uniqueId but it only ends up rerendering the component in a endless loop. What did you use?

Comment: It works but it throws "warning `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop" (React 15)

Comment: @ArjunU. That means you're accessing `props.key`, which is not what I suggested.

Comment: @BenAlpert No I'm not.

Comment: Does this technique call getInitialState again?

Comment: This seems to be an older answer for an older version. Is this technique still applicable in React 16+ version? The updated documentation doesn't seem to mention anything like this. Or have I missed something?

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the inside of a component without requiring the outside to pass a key prop?

Comment: dear colleagues, would you mind to provide some link to documentation or help me to understand why "when key changes, that component will be thrown away and created from scratch"?

Comment: @pospolitaki https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key

However, I'm not a huge fan of relying on `key` for non-lists. It's too easy to forget to use it the next time I use my component.

Answer (score 25):

Adding a `key` attribute to the element that you need to reinitialize, will reload it every time the `props` or `state` associate to the element change.

> key={new Date().getTime()}

Here is an example:

```
render() {
  const items = (this.props.resources) || [];
  const totalNumberOfItems = (this.props.resources.noOfItems) || 0;

  return (
    <div className="items-container">
      <PaginationContainer
        key={new Date().getTime()}
        totalNumberOfItems={totalNumberOfItems}
        items={items}
        onPageChange={this.onPageChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Or you could add a simple integer counter variable as key

Comment: `new Date().getTime()` can be simplified to `Date.now()`. But using Date is an overkill anyway, since you can just do `key={this.counter++}`

Answer (score 14):

You should actually avoid `replaceState` and use `setState` instead.

The docs say that `replaceState` "may be removed entirely in a future version of React." I think it will most definitely be removed because `replaceState` doesn't really jive with the philosophy of React. It facilitates making a React component begin to feel kinda swiss knife-y.
This grates against the natural growth of a React component of becoming smaller, and more purpose-made.

In React, if you have to err on generalization or specialization: aim for specialization. As a corollary, the state tree for your component should have a certain parsimony (it's fine to tastefully break this rule if you're scaffolding out a brand-spanking new product though).

Anyway this is how you do it. Similar to Ben's (accepted) answer above, but like this:

```
this.setState(this.getInitialState());
```

Also (like Ben also said) in order to reset the "browser state" you need to remove that DOM node. Harness the power of the vdom and use a new `key` prop for that component. The new render will replace that component wholesale.

Reference: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#replacestate

Comment: This won't work if the current state includes any properties that are not in the initial state.  While I don't believe that is a great "state" of affairs to be in, unless you can somehow prevent it, I'd want to avoid surprising breakage. I'd be OK with a reset that *crashes* in some cases, but not a reset that subtly corrupts state.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Are you saying this isn't equivalent to `this.replaceState`? Cuz it is.

Comment: @williamle8300 They wouldn't be equivalent if a new property is added to state somewhere in the component lifecycle between calls to`getInitialState()` (say, in an onClick handler). In this case, that new property would still be present after the 2nd `getInitialState()`.

Comment: @Graham I believe it's bad practice to introduce new state to a component that isn't already declared in `getInitialState`. Much like declaring all of your variables in a JS Function at the top of the function. Side note: Ben Alpert's solution is near identical to mine... and he's an official React maintainer!

Comment: @williamle8300: I edited the question with a link to a demo highlighting the differences between set- and replace- state; in short, there is a difference, and replaceState is more robust. Frankly, if I had to pick, I'd prefer deprecating setState and keeping replaceState since replaceState is conceptually more minimal - setState is in essence a replace with an extend.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne I see the JSFiddle, but nothing in it demonstrates your claim that `replaceState` is more robust than `setState`

Comment: click bar, then try the two reset methods.

Comment: @williamle8300 Oh I agree completely that it would be bad practise, but the reality is that the methods *are* different :)

Comment: I am afraid the function getInitialState(), and hence the answer, is deprecated. An update would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

The approach where you add a `key` property to the element and control its value from the parent works correctly. This is because `key` is a declared prop that is used by React for internal purposes and changing it causes the component to reset. Here is an example of how you use a component to reset itself.

The key is controlled in the parent element, but the function that updates the key is passed as a prop to the main element. That way, the button that resets a form can reside in the form component itself.

```js
const InnerForm = (props) => {
  const { resetForm } = props;
  const [value, setValue] = useState('initialValue');

  return (
    <>
      Value: {value}
      <button onClick={() => { setValue('newValue'); }}>
        Change Value
      </button>
      <button onClick={resetForm}>
        Reset Form
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export const App = (props) => {
  const [resetHeuristicKey, setResetHeuristicKey] = useState(false);
  const resetForm = () => setResetHeuristicKey(!resetHeuristicKey);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Form</h1>
      <InnerForm key={resetHeuristicKey} resetForm={resetForm} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Example code (reset the `MyFormComponent` and it's state after submitted successfully):

```
function render() {
    const [formkey, setFormkey] = useState( Date.now() )

    return <>
        <MyFormComponent key={formkey} handleSubmitted={()=>{
            setFormkey( Date.now() )
        }}/>
    </>
}
```

Comment: If you do `useState(Date.now())` you will be calling `Date.now()` on every render. To avoid that you can have an initializer `useState(() => Date.now())`. But all that is unnecessary since `formkey` could be an integer counter and you can do `setFormkey(k => k + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the method reset() of the form:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

interface Props {
    data: string;
}

function Demo(props: Props) {
    const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement | null>(null);

    function resetHandler() {
        formRef.current?.reset();
    }

    return(
        <form ref={formRef}>
            <input defaultValue={props.data}/>
            <button onClick={resetHandler}>reset</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

npm install uuid

```
    import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
        
      [...]

        const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([]);

        function handleGenerateNumbers() {
            setNumbers([]);
        
            let fakeNumbers = [];
        
            for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                let randomFakeNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
        
                fakeNumbers.push(
                    <span key={uuidv4()}>
                        <Number key={uuidv4()} index={i} lotteryColor={lotteryColor} number={randomFakeNumber} />
                    </span>
                );
            }
            setNumbers(fakeNumbers);
        }

[...]
```

Comment: Using a random key was already suggested in other answers. Using uuid in this case would be an overkill and it will slow down the UI. A simple integer counter would suffice to get a key that changes on render.

Comment: a simple integer counter in some cases will not work as expected. For example, when an element with key=0 has already exists

Comment: But you control the entire `numbers` array. If you are worried about the programmer merging the `numbers` array with another array (which might contain the same keys) it would be simpler to warn them about it then to tell them to install another npm package as a workaround