# How do I auto-save with multiple form fields in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, autosave

I have an onBlur on input text fields which auto-saves the record; The data structure is one document which contains an array of items. If i change an item's first column and then the second column quickly, the first column's save would cause an update which would reload both input fields.

How can i prevent the first save from reloading the entire row so both column values get saved?

Here's the code snippet (I mimiced a server save with a `setTimeout`):

```
class Store {
  static doc = {title: "test title", items: [{id: 1, one: "aa", two: "bbb"}, {id: 2, one: "yyy", two: "zzz"}]};

  static getDocument() {
    return this.doc;
  }

  static saveDocument(doc) {
      this.doc = doc;
  }

  static updateItemInDocument(item, callback) {
      var foundIndex;
      let updatedEntry = this.doc.items.find( (s, index) => {
        foundIndex = index;
        return s.id === item.id;
      });

      this.doc.items[foundIndex] = item;
      setTimeout(() => { console.log("updated"); callback(); }, 1000);
  }
};

const Row = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {item: this.props.item};  
  },

  update() {
    let document = Store.getDocument();

    let updatedEntry = document.items.find( (s) => {
            return s.id === this.props.item.id;
        } );

     this.setState({ item: updatedEntry});
  },

  handleEdit() {
    this.setState({item: {
        id: this.props.item.id,
        one: this.refs.one.value,
        two: this.refs.two.value
      }
    });  
  },

  handleSave() {
    Store.updateItemInDocument(this.state.item, this.update);
  },

  render() {
    let item = this.state.item;
    console.log(item);
    return  <tr> <p>Hello</p>
        <input ref="one" type="text" onChange={this.handleEdit} onBlur={this.handleSave} value={item.one} />
        <input ref="two" type="text" onChange={this.handleEdit} onBlur={this.handleSave} value={item.two} />
      </tr>;
  }
});

const App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    let rows = Store.getDocument().items.map( (item, i) => {
      return <Row key={i} item={item} />;
    });

    return <table>
      {rows}
      </table>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

I also have the code as a codepen: http://codepen.io/tommychheng/pen/zBNxeW?editors=1010

Comment: `item` always and only has the properties `one` and `two`? Or can `item` have more or less than those properties?

Comment: item has a fixed number of properties(just one and two) and input fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue stems from the fact that [tabbing out of an input field fires both the `onChange` and `onBlur` handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785099/what-is-the-difference-between-onblur-and-onchange-attribute-in-html/873541#873541).

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your use case, but here's how I'd fix this issue:

```
const Row = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { item: this.props.item };
  },

  handleSave() {
    let item = {
      id: this.state.item.id,
      one: this.refs.one.value,
      two: this.refs.two.value
    }
    Store.updateItemInDocument(item); // Is it really necessary to use the callback here?
  },

  render() {
    let item = this.state.item;
    return (
      <tr>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <input ref="one" type="text" onBlur={this.handleSave} defaultValue={item.one} />
        <input ref="two" type="text" onBlur={this.handleSave} defaultValue={item.two} />
      </tr>
    );
  }
});
```

I switched from using the `onChange` handler to [using a defaultValue](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#uncontrolled-components).

Comment: Thanks Ashitaka! i didn't know of defaultValue. It does solve this issue of an update overwriting the values after an update. My issue looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946229/how-do-i-reset-the-defaultvalue-for-a-react-input/37946963 where a commenter suggests using ``defaultValue`` results in a ``uncontrolled component``which is a bad practice. Do you have any thoughts about an ``uncontrolled component``?

Comment: I don't think using `defaultValue` is a bad practice at all. It depends on your use cases. In this case, I think using `defaultValue` is perfectly valid.