# ReactJS clearing an input from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm teaching myself react with a super simple app that asks the user to type a word presented in the UI.  If user enters it correctly, the app shows another word, and so on.

I've got it almost working, except for one thing: after a word is entered correctly, I need to clear the input element.  I've seen several answers here about how an input element can clear itself, but I need to clear it from the component that contains it, because that's where the input is checked...

```
// the app
class AppComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        words: ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie'],
        index: 0
      };
    }
    renderWordsource() {
      const word = this.state.words[this.state.index];
      return <WordsourceComponent value={ word } />;
    }
    renderWordinput() {
      return <WordinputComponent id={1} onChange={ this.onChange.bind(this) }/>;
    }
    onChange(id, value) {
        const word = this.state.words[this.state.index];
        if (word == value) {
            alert('yes');
            var nextIndex = (this.state.index == this.state.words.count-1)? 0 : this.state.index+1;
            this.setState({ words:this.state.words, index:nextIndex });
        }
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="index">
          <div>{this.renderWordsource()}</div>
          <div>{this.renderWordinput()}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

// the input component
class WordinputComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = { text:''}
    }
    handleChange(event) {
      var text = event.target.value;
      this.props.onChange(this.props.id, text);
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="wordinput-component">
          <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

See where it says `alert('yes')`?  That's where I think I should clear the `value`, but that doesn't make any sense because it's a parameter, not really the state of the component.  Should I have the component pass itself to the change function?  Maybe then I could alter it's state, but that sounds like a bad idea design-wise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 2 common ways of doing this is controlling the value through state in the parent or using a ref to clear the value. Added examples of both

The first one is using a ref and putting a function in the child component to clear
The second one is using state of the parent component and a controlled input field to clear it

```js
class ParentComponent1 extends React.Component {
  state = {
    input2Value: ''
  }
  clearInput1() {
    this.input1.clear();
  }
  clearInput2() {
    this.setState({
      input2Value: ''
    });
  }
  handleInput2Change(evt) {
    this.setState({
      input2Value: evt.target.value
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent1 ref={input1 => this.input1 = input1}/>
        <button onClick={this.clearInput1.bind(this)}>Clear</button>
        <ChildComponent2 value={this.state.input2Value} onChange={this.handleInput2Change.bind(this)}/>
        <button onClick={this.clearInput2.bind(this)}>Clear</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ChildComponent1 extends React.Component {
  clear() {
    this.input.value = '';
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <input ref={input => this.input = input} />
    );
  }
}

class ChildComponent2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <input value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.onChange} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ParentComponent1 />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is very helpful!  Thanks so much.  Can you comment on the advisability of one over the other?  Seems like holding the child's state would eventually bloat the parent with child details, but that calling a function on the ref seems not as declarative as react wants things to be?

Comment: I think for simple use cases using the ref to clear is fine and probably preferable. Its also good when you don't ever need to change the value of a child from a parent. On the other hand having the state in a parent or some store component is better when you need to change the value from a parent. (Otherwise for changing a child's value you would also need to write another method in the child) Its also useful for when you need to submit the form, to have a parent component which has access to all the values to do validation.

Comment: Wow, it's amazing

Comment: @noveyak thank you for your answer! Do you know how to integrate it with useDebonce hook? Assumming that the responsability of debounce the value is part of the ChildComponent2.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue: I wanted to clear a form which contained multiple fields.

While the [two solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43267729/575699) by @noveyak are working fine, I want to share a different idea, which gives me the ability to partition the responsibility between parent and child: parent knows when to clear the form, and the items know how to react to that, without using refs.

The idea is to use a revision counter which gets incremented each time Clear is pressed and to react to changes of this counter in children.

In the example below there are three quite simple children reacting to the Clear button.

```js
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {revision: 0}
  clearInput = () => {
    this.setState((prev) => ({revision: prev.revision+1}))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent revision={this.state.revision}/>
        <ChildComponent revision={this.state.revision}/>
        <ChildComponent revision={this.state.revision}/>
        <button onClick={this.clearInput.bind(this)}>Clear</button>        
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {value: ''}
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(this.props.revision != nextProps.revision){
      this.setState({value : ''});
    }
  }
  saveValue = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.saveValue} />
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<ParentComponent />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:**
I've just stumbled upon this beautifully simple [solution with key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21750576/575699) which is somewhat similar in spirit (you can pass parents's `revision` as child's `key`)

Answer (score 0):

Very very very simple solution to clear form is add unique `key` in div under which you want to render form from your child component `key={new Date().getTime()}`:

```
render(){

        return(
            <div className="form_first_step fields_black" key={new Date().getTime()}>
                <Form
                className="first_step">
                
                  // form fields coming from child component
                  <AddressInfo />
                
                
                </div>
              </Form>
          </div>
        )
    }
```