# Proper ref handling with react-simple-keyboard

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-simple-keyboard

I am using `react-simple-keyboard`, and clearing my input by calling the `useState` hook's setter with an empty string clears the input but doesn't clear the keyboard's "memory", so the next time you type you are adding to the old string again.

`react-simple-keyboard` (RSK) has a `clearInput` function that does the trick, and (as I understand it) it has to be called on the `keyboardRef`. So I rigged that up:

#### my keyboard component (wrapper)

```js
export default KeyboardElement = ({ onChange, keyboardRef }) => {
  return <KeyboardContainer>
    <Keyboard
      layout={ {
        'default': [
          '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0',
          'Q W E R T Y U I O P',
          'A S D F G H J K L',
          'Z X C V B N M {bksp}',
        ],
      } }
      theme={ 'firmm-keyboard' }
      keyboardRef={ keyboardRef }
      onChange={ onChange }
    />
  </KeyboardContainer>;
};
```

#### consuming component

```js
export default LicenseEntry = ({ onClose }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const keyboard = useRef();

  const onClear = () => {
    // @ts-ignore
    keyboard.current!.clearInput();
    setText('');
  };

  return (
    <FullScreenModalBackground zIndex={ 9 }>
      <OuterContainer>
        <InnerContainer>
          <ExitButton onClose={ onClose }/>
          <HeaderText>Add license</HeaderText>
          <Input
            readOnly
            data-testid="LICENSE_INPUT"
            value={ formatLicense(text) }
            placeholder={ 'type license here' }
          />
          <KeyboardElement
            keyboardRef={ r => keyboard.current = r }
            onChange={ setText }
          />
          <Button>Submit</Button>
          <Button onClick={ onClear }>Clear</Button>
        </InnerContainer>
      </OuterContainer>
    </FullScreenModalBackground>
  );
};
```

This works, but has a code smell: I'm creating the ref in the consuming component (I'm then passing it to my keyboard wrapper so that RSK can use it, and I can call `clearInput` on it), and using the RSK method in the consuming component instead of the keyboard wrapper.

It seems wrong that the component using the keyboard should be using and knowing about the RSK's ref. It also means that the type of `keyboard.current!` in the consuming component is `never` (or some other unmanageable type) and so I'm using the `@ts-ignore` as a band aid.

What is the proper correct way to go about this?

Update: I've tried the [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266582/reactjs-clearing-an-input-from-parent-component) but it's not working. The only change I actually make is that I don't used the passed `ref` in the inner component (`KeyboardElement`) and I define a `clearInput` function on `KeyboardElement` which just calls *its* ref's `clearInput` function. But the ref in the consuming component is always `undefined`.

I think the difference between my situation and the other one is that I'm not calling a function of the ref, I'm calling the function of the "nested ref". I'm passing the parent's ref to the child as a prop so that the child can assign *its* ref to that prop, and that seems wrong.

Comment: Read this post out, you'll get the idea very vividly
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266582/reactjs-clearing-an-input-from-parent-component

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't quite working for me. See my update.

Comment: you either clear the value with setting hooks value to '' " or use Ref. Do one of the either, not both. I'll prefer you go with just clearing the hook value. No typescript or types error there.

Comment: Clearing the hooks value indeed clears *my* component's text. But the `react-simple-keyboard` is storing its *own* state that tracks the keys that have been pressed, which means the next time you type after clearing the hook value, you still have the keys previously pressed. The only way I can find to clear the keyboard's own state is using its `clearInput` method. I did try the "use a key" tactic in the linked post, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Hey @JonathanTuzman, did you get this fixed on your end? I see no issue with this approach: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/simple-keyboard/react-simple-keyboard-typescript-hooks/tree/master/ but feel free to respond here or file an issue in the Github repo and I'll take a look! Thanks

Comment: Thanks @FranciscoHodge. I actually took another tack -- instead of using my clear button to call the nested `keyboard.clearInput`, I used the keyboard as a more truly controlled component, where the change handler for my `simple-keyboard` passed the typed character up to its parent's handler and then `clearInput` cleared the keyboard's buffer, so that the keyboard was only ever dealing with one character at a time.

Answer (score 4):

the way i got this working with version 3.1.9 was to also import `KeyboardReactInterface`

```
import Keyboard, { KeyboardReactInterface } from 'react-simple-keyboard'

const keyboardRef = useRef<KeyboardReactInterface | null>(null)

<Keyboard
  keyboardRef={(r) => (keyboardRef.current = r)}
  onChange={onChange}
  onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
  layoutName={layoutName}
/>
```