# Easy way to set default state values in React JS component

Tags: reactjs, react-state

Is there any easy way to set component's state convert to default state.

Normally I create a function for this by setting a default values like below. Is there other way instead of this?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Person extends Component {
    state = {
        firstName: null,
        lastName : null,
        age      : null,
        address  : null,
    }

    // Set state to default state
    setDefaultState = () => {
        this.setState({
            firstName: null,
            lastName : null,
            age      : null,
            address  : null,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                Person Component
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Person;
```

Is there any pre-defined function for this in react js.

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749798/how-can-i-reset-a-react-component-including-all-transitively-reachable-state

Comment: In that answer, what saying is, there isn't a pre-define function for this. What I need is, when I create a modal, I need to set it's state to default state when it is hidden. For that I'm currently using like above function which is in my question `setDefaultState()`. What I'm asking is, is there any **pre-defined function** in react js instead of my current approach.

Comment: Yes,sorry to mislead what you are doing is the same that is followed by others including me. Happy coding !

Comment: Okay thank you @ThakurKarthik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is an approach

```
initialState = {
    firstName: null,
    lastName : null,
    age      : null,
    address  : null,
}

class Person extends Component {
    state = {
        ...initialState
    }

    // Set state to default state
    setDefaultState = () => {
        this.setState({
            ...initialState
        });
    }
```

Comment: **True**. But is there any pre-defined function to do this instead of creating a new function to convert current state to default state in react js?