# How to reset a value of an uncontrolled React component that uses DraftJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a reusable component that wrap [draftJS](https://draftjs.org/).

My component is "uncontrolled" as it is getting an initalValue that i put in the state of the draftJs component on mount.

My question is - how to give my user the option to clear, to reset, the value of my component?

I thought maybe to expose to the user an `onInitial(resetFunc)` prop  which i will run  inside `componentDidMount`, he will then keep a refrence to this resetFunc to execute whenever he wishes.

`ResetFunc` will be a function inside my comopnent that will change the state appropriately to reset the value.

This solution is not straightforward, wdyt?

Comment: Consider a nonce key. When you want to reset the component, change the key. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749798/how-can-i-reset-a-react-component-including-all-transitively-reachable-state#21750576

Comment: Great to hear, I added it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a nonce key to reset the tree, as described this answer: [How can I reset a react component including all transitively reachable state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749798/how-can-i-reset-a-react-component-including-all-transitively-reachable-state#21750576)