# How can I force a component to "reset" when a prop changes in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a pretty complex chatbox component that fetches chats depending on which channel is selected. I'm running into issues where changing the channel (which is then passed in as a prop) is causing issues, due to the existing data in the prop from the previous channel.
Is there a way I can "reset" the entire component when the prop is changed? Meaning all hooks and whatnot are reset back to default, like in the first render.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! It would be great if you could provide some of the code that you are attempting to use or a minimal reproduction of your chatbox. If you are using react hooks you may want to look into the `useEffect` hook to update your state on prop change. Hard to say without seeing some code though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reset a react component including all transitively reachable state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749798/how-can-i-reset-a-react-component-including-all-transitively-reachable-state)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

Set the `key` prop on a the component you'd like to completely re-initialize
Details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21750576/6702598

Answer (score 0):

you can use key props to the main component which you want to reset all. I think the key can be the id of the chanel

Answer (score -1):

don't update props value.

create a state, then set that state to the value of the prop that is passed down on

```
componentDidMount{
    //set state here
 }
```

or

```
 useEffect(() => { 
    //set state here
  },[])
```

this wiil update the state each time the new props is passed down. and then you would use the values of the state however you like.

Comment: I tried, for instance, to reset the message array to empty in useEffect, but I also want to trigger the "get initial messages" function, which doubles as a "get more function", that appends new messages to the existing array. The array isn't empty by the time the function is called, desbite setMessages([]) appearing above it in the useEffect method.

Comment: is it possible for you to provide the code for the component that you want the reset to happen in?