# How to destroy and reinitialize component in react on Button click in another component

Tags: reactjs

I have created a Pagination from a tutorial in React like this,

```
 const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]); 
 const [showPerPage] = useState(6);
 const [pagination, setPagination] = useState({
   start: 0,
   end: showPerPage
 });
 const onPaginationChange = (start, end) => {
   setPagination({start: start, end: end});
 }
```

The above lines are in the main Component in which I am calling my Pagination component like this:

```
<Pagination showPerPage={showPerPage} onPaginationChange={onPaginationChange} totalProvider={posts.length}/>
```

Now I have created the Pagination Component like this,

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const Pagination = ({showPerPage, onPaginationChange, totalProvider}) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
    useEffect(()=>{
        const value = showPerPage * counter;
        onPaginationChange(value - showPerPage, value);
    },[counter]);
    const onButtonClick = (type) => {
        if(type==='prev'){
            if(counter === 1){
                setCounter(1);
            }else {
                setCounter(counter - 1);
            }
        }else if( type=== 'next'){
            if(Math.ceil(totalProvider/showPerPage)=== counter){
                setCounter(counter);
            }else {
                setCounter(counter + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className="paginationWrapper">
            <span id="prevBtn" onClick={()=>onButtonClick('prev')} className="disable">Prev.</span>
            <div className="numberOfItems">
                <span id="startCounter">{counter}</span>of<span>{Math.ceil(totalProvider/showPerPage)}</span>    
            </div>   
            <span id="nextBtn" onClick={()=>onButtonClick('next')}>Next</span>        
        </div>
    )
}


export default Pagination
```

This is the Setup I have, Now I want to reset the Pagination when I click on a button in Parent Component, Because on that button click I need to fetch more or less data, and in this case my pagination always stay on the number where I previously left it,
I can do this 2 ways, but unable to get the code way:

1. If I can reset the counter (const in Pagination component)to 1, on that button click, then it would be done, Or
2. If I can just destroy the Component, every State of it, then it would be done.

Please help,
Note: I am not using redux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reset a react component including all transitively reachable state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749798/how-can-i-reset-a-react-component-including-all-transitively-reachable-state)

Answer (score 0):

I think using ref is the easiest way to do it.

```
import React, {userRef} from "react"
function ParentComponent() {
    const resetRef = useRef();
    const handleReset = () => {
         if (resetRef && resetReft.current) resetRef.current.resetCounter();
    }
    return <>
          <button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</button>
          <Pagination ref={resetRef} showPerPage={showPerPage} onPaginationChange={onPaginationChange} totalProvider={posts.length}/>
       </>
}
```

Add forwardRef and resetCounter() to your Pagination component.

```
 
const Pagination = React.forwardRef(({showPerPage, onPaginationChange, totalProvider}, ref) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
    useEffect(()=>{
        const value = showPerPage * counter;
        onPaginationChange(value - showPerPage, value);
    },[counter]);
    const onButtonClick = (type) => {
        if(type==='prev'){
            if(counter === 1){
                setCounter(1);
            }else {
                setCounter(counter - 1);
            }
        }else if( type=== 'next'){
            if(Math.ceil(totalProvider/showPerPage)=== counter){
                setCounter(counter);
            }else {
                setCounter(counter + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    resetCounter() {
        setCounter(1);
    }
    return (
        <div className="paginationWrapper" ref={ref}>
            <span id="prevBtn" onClick={()=>onButtonClick('prev')} className="disable">Prev.</span>
            <div className="numberOfItems">
                <span id="startCounter">{counter}</span>of<span>{Math.ceil(totalProvider/showPerPage)}</span>    
            </div>   
            <span id="nextBtn" onClick={()=>onButtonClick('next')}>Next</span>        
        </div>
    )
})


export default Pagination
```

Comment: this is the error I got after excuteing the code you suggested, Please help. Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'resetCounter' of undefined